# "ImportError: No module named six" ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

when running "src/bitmessagemain.py" in the terminal it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/bitmessagemain.py", line 33, in <module>
    import shared
  File "/home/otsudo/Desktop/PyBitmessage-0.6/src/shared.py", line 19, in <module>
    import highlevelcrypto
  File "/home/otsudo/Desktop/PyBitmessage-0.6/src/highlevelcrypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from bmconfigparser import BMConfigParser
  File "/home/otsudo/Desktop/PyBitmessage-0.6/src/bmconfigparser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six import string_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

I am guessing it has to do something with the virtualenv due to bitmessage still running on python 2.7 but I cant figure it out. I've made the environment for bitmessage to run in and I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the six Python module installed,
try this:

```
pip install six
```

Comment: Thank you but I believe i do have it installed. It returns "Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.14.0)" when I enter "pip install six" in the terminal.

Comment: It's likely that you do not have the packaged installed in the venv as the terminal will default to desktop install. Alternatively the package is installed in venv and you are not running your script with venv activated.

Comment: yep that worked! thank you @born_naked